# Change chart subtitle programmatically

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Maybe not the best title, but what I'm trying to do is change the *subtitle* of my chart to include the last temperature displayed in it. Something like this

*Last value: 4 degrees*

The chart's data is in a csv file.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var lastVal = 0;
    $.get('csv/Temp.csv', function (csv) {
        $('#Temp').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'spline',
                zoomType: 'xy'
            },
            data: {
                csv: csv
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Outside Temperature'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Last value: '
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Units'
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

If I change the *subtitle* to:

```
subtitle: {
      text: function () {
          lastVal = this.yData[this.yData.length - 1];
          return 'Last Value: ' + lastVal;
      }
},
```

I only get the text. How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the chart subtitle programmatically using the function ([API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.setTitle)):

```
chart.setTitle(Object title, object subtitle, Boolean redraw)
```

An example would be:

```
chart.setTitle(null, { text: "New subtitle" }, true);
```

If you want this to happen on load with data from CSV, you could do it like this ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qoa7pfz4/2/)):

```
chart: {
    events: {
        load: function(event) {
            var lastValue = this.series[0].data[this.series[0].data.length-1].y;
            this.setTitle(null,{ text: 'Last y-value: '+lastValue }, true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, your answer is very clear and I was able to change the subtitle. Thank you!